# Is it possible to get stats on combined categories from Sendgrid Web API v3

Tags: api, sendgrid

I am successfully querying the Sendgrid Web API v3 for category stats, using the following endpoint, as documented at [Web API v3 Category Stats](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Stats/categories.html);

```
https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/categories/stats?start_date=2015-01-01&end_date=2015-01-02&categories=sales&categories=north&categories=tech
```

This returns the stats for each category. So I get a row of data for *Sales*, a row for *North* and a row for *Tech*.

What I really want is to make custom queries for cross-sections of categories. So I'd actually like to know the stats for emails that had the categories of both **Sales** and **Tech** for example.

Is there any way to this via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this via the API after the emails have been sent. If you know which categories you want grouped, you can specify a unique common category at send time for emails that have category `sales` OR `tech` and then query based on that super-category.